# Exchange Powershell Script consumes all system resources on local pc

Tags: arrays, powershell, exchange-server

I'm back!

Anyway, I'm running an exchange script to find emails that contain a specific list of keywords for a specific set of users, defined as users and terms in the script below, and it works. However after about an hour or so of running, it's consuming obnoxious amounts of memory, 12 - 14 GB. and running very slowly.

It does flux between 3 GB and 14 GB, so I don't know if this is simply normal, expected behavior or if its' something wrong with my script. I am aware that I'm using a sorta(?) depreciated commandlet in the search-mailbox function, but I'm only searching about 300 users and 21 terms, so I don't think I need to use the new-mailboxsearch commandlet.

Script for Reference

```
$users = Get-Content x:\xxx\xxx\users.txt 
$terms = Get-Content x:\xxx\xxx\Terms.txt

ForEach ($term in $Terms) {
     ForEach ($line in $users) {
            $Results = Search-Mailbox -Identity $line -SearchQuery $term -TargetMailbox SearchResults2 -TargetFolder $term -LogLevel Full | Select Identity,TargetFolder,ResultItemsCount
            Add-Content -Path x:\xxx\xxx\outputfile.txt -Value "$($term);$($line);$($Results.TargetFolder);$($Results.ResultItemsCount)"
    }
}
```

Anyway, any help is, as always, greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So $users isn't used there?  What is $ambassadors?

Comment: It's a typo lol, I updated it to reflect my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn’t with the script itself, it was the environment we were running it in.

For some reason running the script inside of the integrated scripting environment Powershell ISE, was causing the script to suck up crazy amounts of memory, eventually halting the system. By simply launching it outside of the ISE we were able to get the script to behave normally:

Thanks to everyone who replied!

Answer (score 0):

Does foreach-object fair better?

```
$terms | ForEach { $term = $_
  $users | ForEach { $line = $_
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to test using this method this evening. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Hey guys, question if I’m using the ISE instead of just plain old PS, does that make a difference in memory utilization? Changing the script to foreach-object actually made it eat up more resources and at a faster rate than just foreach, granted it also ran way faster. 

However if i drop out of ise and just load ps and run the script from there, it seems to be working much better.

Comment: So, powershell ISE was the issue. I’m not sure why precisely, but when we run the script in plain old powershell it doesn’t have this problem at all.  

Thanks for all the help!